# Login page not working

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am having a weird problem. I created a login page and whenever focused is entered on any text box, the page reloads itself. Please check http://oasisitsolutions.com/Login.aspx

I am using HTML5, EntityFramework.

Webconfig file contians

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" name="CustomizedRoleProvider" type="CustomizedRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" type="CustomizedMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

Thanks in advance,

Dinesh

Comment: what is the code of your login page?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting us to do? Read all the hundreds of lines of JavaScript? I think you should put in a bit more effort and then ask a proper question.

Comment: @ChaosPandion There is not any javascript code or any page behind code, the problem was in HTML.

Comment: @SteveB Thanks for giving hand for help but the problem was in html and now fixed.

Comment: @DineshAhuja - You have quite a pair to say that after you've been given a solution.

Comment: @SteveB If you would have checked page then you would have noticed that there is no javascript i have attached but never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinesh, it's actually not anything tied to the focus() event - your entire page is wrapped in an extra `<a href="Login.aspx">` tag located directly under your nav container.  So, anytime you click on anything within that anchor tag (including the textboxes), it's going to execute as if you clicked on that link and navigate back to Login.aspx.

Just remove that tag and it will stop refreshing anytime you click.